# Proving an algebraic identity using the axioms of field

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to prove (based on the axioms of field) that
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
So, my first thought was to use the distributive law to show that
$$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=(a-b)\cdot a^2+(a-b)\cdot ab+(a-b)\cdot b^2$$
And then continuing from this point.
My problem is that I'm not sure if the distributive law is enough to prove this identity. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to prove that $(-x)y = x(-y) = -(xy)$ for all $x,y$, and you'll also be using associativity and commutativity (e.g., to get from $b\cdot ab$ to $ab^2$).

Comment: I think I know how to do the rest, my question was if this identity (the second one I wrote) could be justified relaying on the distributive law alone?

Comment: You are using distributivity and associativity; the distributivity axiom only tells you what to do when you have $x(y+z)$; here you have $x(y+z+w)$, so you must view it as $x((y+z)+w) = x(y+z) + xw = (xy+xz) + xw = xy+xz+xw$ (or as $x(y+(z+w)) = xy+x(z+w)= xy+(xz+xw) = xy+xz+xw$. Or form a "generalized distributivity", $a\sum b_i = \sum ab_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you need *distributive*, *associative* and *commutative laws* to prove your statement.

In fact:
$$\begin{split}
(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) &= (a+(-b))a^2 +(a+(-b))ab+(a+(-b))b^2\\
&= a^3 +(- b)a^2+a^2b+(-b)(ab)+ab^2+(-b)b^2\\
&= a^3 - ba^2+a^2b - b(ab) +ab^2-b^3\\
&= a^3 - a^2b+a^2b - (ba)b +ab^2-b^3\\
&= a^3 -(ab)b +ab^2-b^3\\
&= a^3 -ab^2 +ab^2-b^3\\
&= a^3-b^3\; .
\end{split}$$